# How to apply dagger 2 to compose desktop project

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, dagger-2, compose-desktop

I have created a new *Compose Multiplatform* project with IJ Idea (single desktop platform).

Trying to add dagger to `build.gradle.kts` template:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
    kotlin("kapt") version "1.8.0" //Add kapt-plugin --OK
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        jvmToolchain(11)
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
                implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.45") //add dependency --OK
                kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.45") //add compiler for kapt --NOT-OK
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}

...
```

Got design-time error about Type missmatch (required Action, found String).
What is correct way to apply dagger2 for the `build.gradle` template generated with IJ Idea?